# How to extract a particular string( email )from a file through php

Tags: php

I have a text file having some members information about organizational experts. Now I want to extract only email addresses from that.

**Example file:**

```
a@a.com jhgvhdhf bahau@gmail.com hdghfd  G@g.com
```

How could I extract all the strings ending with `@hotmail.com`? If the filename is foo.txt...

Answer (score 0):

Load the data into a string (I'm using `$str` for that) and apply a email regular expression:

```
$pattern = '/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[^\.].*\.[a-z]{2,}/i';
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)){
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

As Guy commented below, you can load the file into a string with:

```
$str = file_get_contents('/path/to/file');
```

**EDIT:**

For hotmail, you can change the pattern to:

```
$pattern = '/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@hotmail.com/i';
```

Comment: Just pin point the fact that you can get the `$str` with `$str = file_get_contents('/path/to/file');`

Comment: How could I extract the all of strings with @hotmail.com,at the end. If the txt file's name is foo.txt,

Comment: I updated for hotmail.